# When momentum coincides with impulse

Tags: forces, momentum, definition

If an object is pushed for some time by some force from a resting state, can I say that at the exact moment the force is removed, impulse equals momentum?

Comment: Why shouldn't you? Since impulse is change in momentum, the impulse from zero momentum to some momentum is exactly that some momentum, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ....  can I say that at the exact moment the force is removed, impulse
>   equals **momentum**?

Yes, but it is more correct to say that "it equals the **change** (increase/decrease) **of momentum**"

Force is an abstract concept. As defined by *wiki*:

> A **force** is any interaction which tends to change the motion of an
>   object.[1] In other words, a force can cause an object with mass to
>   change its velocity (which includes to begin moving from a state of
>   rest), i.e., to accelerate. Force can also be described by intuitive
>   concepts such as a push or a pull. A force has both **magnitude** and
>   **direction**, making it a **vector** quantity. It is measured in the SI unit
>   of newtons and represented by the symbol F.

it is a mathematical definition: $\vec{F} =m \vec{a}$ that states that if a constant force is applied to a (massive) body it will get a constant and uniform acceleration.

Whenever a force is actually applied to a body it is applied for a certain time $t$, and the product  $J =(\int{F}dt)=\vec{F}t =m \vec{a} t$ is called [**impulse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_(physics)) : the acceleration produces an increase of the velocity, and since the body has mass an increase of its momentum.

When the original applied force is not known, as in collisions, the end result, the increase of momentum is known and the term *impulse* is used, but there is no substantial difference between them.

Comment: Can force be calculated from only impulse given?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in that instance impulse equal momentum, since impulse equals change in momentum. If the momentum then was 0, and the momentum now is p, then impulse = p - 0 = p.

Comment: "impulse = p - 0 = 0"  - that should read p - 0 = p? By the way, what would force be in that case? Can it be said?

Comment: @PeterBernhard Thanks. That was a typo.